# Congruence Classes of Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, change-of-basis, matrix-congruences

Let A $\in$ K$^n$$^,$$^n$ be a symmetric matrix over a field K. Define f(A) = { t$^2$ det(A) : t $\in$ K } and g(A) = {$x^T$A$x$ : $x \in $ K$^n$ } .

I have shown that if A,B are *congruent*, then f(A) = f(B) and g(A) = g(B).

Suppose A is the matrix of a quadratic form q with respect to some basis. Then we can write f(q) = f(A) and g(q) = g(A). Put K = $Z_3$, the field of three elements. Now using the foregoing, I want to find the *congruence classes* of the quadratic forms in two variables $x, y$ over K and their f- and g-values. (Two quadratic forms are *congruent* if they differ by a change of coordinates)

Can someone help?

Comment: asked yesterday and deleted. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2005011/congruence-classes-of-quadratic-forms